# R : Merge 2 different data frames every x rows ( every 5 rows then 7 then maybe 3 etc)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I need some help merging 2 data frames in RStudio.

I would like to merge my PP data frame into my MergeHeader data frame following this pattern : 
Every time there is an incremented number in the 
`instance_reporting_properties.NumÃ©ro_x0020_du_x0020_formulaire` column, I want to merge one row of the PP data frame.

For example, 
I want to add the 5th row of PP data frame to the row with the Value 5 in the mergeHeader data frame.

Then nothing for a few rows and do it again for the 6th row of PP.
And so forth.
The trick being that there’s not the same number of NA rows between each value(in MergeHeader dataframe).

Here a simplified version of my data frames :

```
     > dput(head(tmpPP, 5))
structure(list(`_x0031__x0020_-_x0020_Type_x0020_de_x0020_demande_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_` = c("Demande de crÃ©ation", 
"Demande de crÃ©ation", NA, NA), `_x0032__x0020_-_x0020_NumÃ©ro_x0020_du_x0020_formulaire_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_` = c("N 5", 
"N 6", NA, NA), `_x0033__x0020_-_x0020_Demandeur_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_` = c("par MOLLE Francois pour", 
"par CABRERA Fabienne pour", NA, NA), `_x0034__x0020_-_x0020_Fournisseur_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_` = c("MONNIEZ CHRISTOPHE JACQUES", 
"A . C . C . REFERENCE TOURS", NA, NA), `_x0035__x0020_-_x0020_Date_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_demande_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_` = c("le Monday, January 2, 2017 8:44:07 AM", 
"le Monday, January 2, 2017 8:56:47 AM", NA, NA), Code_x0020_fournisseur = c("FA01070-59242", 
"FA01792-74000", "FA01072-68110", "En cours"), Code_x0020_NAF = c("1071C", 
"7911Z", NA, NA), Date_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_demande = c("1/2/2017", 
"1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017"), `DÃ©lai_x0020_de_x0020_paiement` = c("45 jours fin de mois", 
"45 jours fin de mois", "Comptant", "Comptant"), Demandeur = c("MOLLE Francois", 
"CABRERA Fabienne", "DI MARCO Elio", "CHOPIN Anne Flore"), Famille_x0020_Achat = c("061101 - Consommables alimentaires, boissons et dÃ©rivÃ©s", 
"060302 - Agences de voyages", NA, NA), Fournisseur = c("MONNIEZ CHRISTOPHE JACQUES", 
"A . C . C . REFERENCE TOURS", "CONTROLE TECHNIQUE PASSION ILLZACH", 
"DIRECTION REGIONALE FINANCES PUBLIQUES PROVENCE ALPES COTE D'AZUR ET DEPARTEMENT BOUCHES DU RHONE"
), Mode_x0020_de_x0020_paiement_x0020_1 = c("VIR", "VIR", "VIR", 
"VIR"), Nom_x0020_Approbateur = c("Vincent DESTOT", "BURTEY Thomas", 
"Laurent GELHAYE", NA), Nom_x0020_Gestionnaire_x0020_RFN = c("Elisa WATELLOO", 
"KOLANUS Karolina", "Elisa WATELLOO", "Elisa WATELLOO"), `NumÃ©ro_x0020_du_x0020_formulaire` = c("5", 
"6", "7", "8"), Personne_x0020_en_x0020_charge = c("RÃ©viseurs", 
"RÃ©viseurs", "RÃ©viseurs", NA), `PÃ´le_x0020_du_x0020_demandeur` = c("Hauts De France", 
"Bourgogne - Franche - ComtÃ©", "Grand Est", "SociÃ©tÃ© EAP"), 
    Statut = c("FinalisÃ©e", "FinalisÃ©e", "FinalisÃ©e", "Demande refusÃ©e Gestionnaire"
    ), Type_x0020_de_x0020_demande = c("Demande de crÃ©ation", 
    "Demande de crÃ©ation", "Demande de crÃ©ation", "Demande de crÃ©ation"
    ), Type_x0020_de_x0020_fournisseur = c("FranÃ§ais", NA, "FranÃ§ais", 
    "FranÃ§ais"), `Date_x0020_de_x0020_crÃ©ation` = c("1/2/2017", 
    "1/1/0001", "1/2/2017", NA), Date_x0020_de_x0020_rejet = c(NA, 
    NA, "1/1/0001", NA), Prestataire_x0020_de_x0020_service = c(NA, 
    "Oui", "Oui", NA), Mode_x0020_de_x0020_paiement_x0020_2 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Motif_x0020_de_x0020_rejet = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `ActivitÃ©_x0020_Tourisme` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), .Names = c("_x0031__x0020_-_x0020_Type_x0020_de_x0020_demande_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_", 
"_x0032__x0020_-_x0020_NumÃ©ro_x0020_du_x0020_formulaire_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_", 
"_x0033__x0020_-_x0020_Demandeur_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_", 
"_x0034__x0020_-_x0020_Fournisseur_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_", 
"_x0035__x0020_-_x0020_Date_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_demande_x0020__x0028_Alias_x0029_", 
"Code_x0020_fournisseur", "Code_x0020_NAF", "Date_x0020_de_x0020_la_x0020_demande", 
"DÃ©lai_x0020_de_x0020_paiement", "Demandeur", "Famille_x0020_Achat", 
"Fournisseur", "Mode_x0020_de_x0020_paiement_x0020_1", "Nom_x0020_Approbateur", 
"Nom_x0020_Gestionnaire_x0020_RFN", "NumÃ©ro_x0020_du_x0020_formulaire", 
"Personne_x0020_en_x0020_charge", "PÃ´le_x0020_du_x0020_demandeur", 
"Statut", "Type_x0020_de_x0020_demande", "Type_x0020_de_x0020_fournisseur", 
"Date_x0020_de_x0020_crÃ©ation", "Date_x0020_de_x0020_rejet", 
"Prestataire_x0020_de_x0020_service", "Mode_x0020_de_x0020_paiement_x0020_2", 
"Motif_x0020_de_x0020_rejet", "ActivitÃ©_x0020_Tourisme"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>, row.names = 5:8, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))





    dputTmp <- dput(head(tmp,18))
structure(list(`instance_reporting_properties.NumÃ©ro_x0020_du_x0020_formulaire` = c("5", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "6", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "7", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "8"), `instance_reporting_properties.PÃ´le_x0020_de_x0020_rattachement` = c("Hauts De France", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Bourgogne - Franche - ComtÃ©", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "Grand Est", NA, NA, NA, NA, "SociÃ©tÃ© EAP")), .Names = c("instance_reporting_properties.NumÃ©ro_x0020_du_x0020_formulaire", 
"instance_reporting_properties.PÃ´le_x0020_de_x0020_rattachement"
), row.names = 21:38, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image. For us to use that, we would have to type it all in again. Instead, use `dput` to create a text version of your data and paste it into your question. if your data is too long, you could provide a sample by using  `dput(head(PP, 20))`

Comment: Ok, i'll fix this right now